# How solve: Future Provider 6.0.2 could not find que correct provider Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I try to use Future Provider in my app but at the time to register it on the top of my widget tree like so:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_9_future_provider/function.dart'; //here is my future class
import 'package:flutter_application_9_future_provider/homescreen.dart'; //here is the screen
import 'package:provider/provider.dart'; 

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  Busqueda bus = Busqueda(); // my class is called "Busqueda" and has a method (buscarrequest)that returns a future
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureProvider(
      initialData: 'vacio',
      create: (context) => bus.buscarrequest(),
      child: const MaterialApp(
        home: Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I get and error that says:

> Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
> The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Home(dirty):
> Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Busqueda> above this Home Widget
>
> This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
> of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:...

Using ChangeNotifier Provider this do not happen, why?
There is some example in the error message but I tried it but do not work:

> For example, instead of:
>
> Widget build(BuildContext context) {
> return Provider<Example>(
> create: (_) => Example(),
> Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
> to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
> child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
> ),
> }
>
> consider using `builder` like so:
>
> Widget build(BuildContext context) {
> return Provider<Example>(
> create: (_) => Example(),
> we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
> builder: (context) {
> No longer throws
> return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
> }
> ),
> }

Please advice in how to solve this error.
Thanks in advance!

Use future provider (provider: ^6.0.2) in flutter app with no error.

Comment: have you registered your provider in your main.dart or app entry

Comment: It is there where the error occurs.

Comment: Where are you using this provider? Can you show the code snippet?

Comment: yes, here it is: https://github.com/waltherpa/example.git